# Random lock timeout error on ArangoDB update

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I got this random timeout error when updating existing document.

```
AQL: timeout waiting to lock key Operation timed out: Timeout waiting to lock key; key: 1013 (while executing)
```

ArangoDB version: 3.9

ArangoJS version :8.0.0

Comment: how do you solve this problem? I'm facing to the same problem with this error when trying to insert massive data to ArnagoDB. I configure the `overwriteMode` paramter to `update` but it doesn't help.

Comment: @gohan I've not solved this issue yet, but my internal team is working to build our own distributed storage system with C++, so practically, we will not use ArangoDB anymore.